# Tabs at the top of the page not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying build a news website but im having a problem with centering the tabs at the top of th page. Can anyone give me some tips on how to fix this and also explain(I'm new to web development).
Thanks in advance.

```css
ul{list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333333;}

        li{float: right;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black}

        li a{display: inline-block;
        background-color: #333333;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;}

        li a:hover {background-color: black;}
```

```html
  <ul role="menubar">
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sport">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#business">Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="#TV">TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#car">Automobiles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#culture">Culture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fashion">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#health">Healthcare</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tourism">Tourism</a></li>
    <li><a href="#TECH">TECH</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Please give us a example, we can work with. What is your exact problem and how exactly should it look like?  
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `li`'s to `display: inline-block` and remove `float: right`. That will allow `text-align: center` on the parent `ul` to center to work.

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
li a{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover{background-color: black;}
```

```html
<ul role="menubar">
    <li></li><li><a href="#news">News</a></li><li><a href="#sport">Sports</a></li><li><a href="#business">Business</a></li><li><a href="#TV">TV</a></li><li><a href="#car">Automobiles</a></li><li><a href="#culture">Culture</a></li><li><a href="#fashion">Fashion</a></li><li><a href="#food">Food</a></li><li><a href="#health">Healthcare</a></li><li><a href="#tourism">Tourism</a></li><li><a href="#TECH">TECH</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Christoph no, I'll include all of the code with it complete and working in my answer, and explain what I changed. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Not sure why @MichaelCoker got downvoted. Gave you an upvote since you did as needed. That way he can run the code...

Comment: @Staveven Yeah for some reason Christoph thinks I shouldn't include all of the code, downvoted me, and edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: Including unnecessary code harms readability. Also, your first edit did not contain any explanation, that's why I downvoted (according to community guidelines). I'm fine with a minimal example and a reasonable explanation as your answer is now. That's why I give +1 instead.

Comment: You are welcome. It did by no means intend to bully you, but just want to help people asking good question and getting clear and precise answers.

Comment: @Christoph np, I appreciate the explanations. I'm kinda new and learning as I go.

Comment: Thank you all for helping. But now there is this between every list item(sorry if I used the wrong term there). how do I remove it?

Comment: @dawed1999 np. Check my edit - I removed the white space between the elements. Does that solve the issue? `inline-block` preserves the white space between elements.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Where is the edit I can't seem to find it and yes that helped.

Comment: @dawed1999 *"I removed the white space between the elements"* all of the `li`'s are now on one line